# Default challenge scheme isn't working with RouteGroups?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, minimal-apis

I have a Route Group for several endpoints:

```
internal class EmployeeRouteGroup : RouteGroup
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override string Prefix => "employees";

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override RouteGroupBuilder ConfigureCommonBehaviour(RouteGroupBuilder routeGroupBuilder)
    {
        return routeGroupBuilder.RequireAuthorization();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override RouteGroupBuilder ConfigureRoutes(RouteGroupBuilder routeGroupBuilder)
    {
        routeGroupBuilder.MapGet("/", async ([AsParameters] SearchEmployeesParametersDto getEmployeesParameters, IMediator mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            => await mediator.Send(new SearchEmployeesQuery { Parameters = getEmployeesParameters }, cancellationToken));

        routeGroupBuilder.MapGet("/{id}", async (int id, IMediator mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            => await mediator.Send(new GetEmployeeDetailsQuery { EmployeeId = id }, cancellationToken));

        routeGroupBuilder.MapGet("/for-salary-access-user/{id}", async (int id, IMediator mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            => await mediator.Send(new SearchEmployeesForSalaryAccessUserQuery { SalaryAccessUserId = id }, cancellationToken));

        return routeGroupBuilder;
    }
}
```

Also in `Startup.cs` I've setup `DefaultChallengeScheme`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o => o = jwtOptions);
```

But everytime when I'm trying to make unauthorized request I get `404` response instead of `401`.

If you put `[Authorize(AuthenticationScheme = ...)]` within endpoint it works fine! But, you know, it's not good approach :)

Comment: You deleted the Keycloak post as I was ready to answer. SPAs don't use redirection like  server-side apps do. The SPA handles talking to Keycloak, retrieving tokens and using them to talk to the server. Keycloak supports OIDC so the doc examples that show how to use OIDC work for Keycloak too. The blog article [Use Keycloak as Identity Provider from Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) applications](https://nikiforovall.github.io/blazor/dotnet/2022/12/08/dotnet-keycloak-blazorwasm-auth.html) shows all the steps, including how to configure Keycloak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in fact that there was an `Identity` setup after `Authentication` setup.

`AddIdentity<>` method contains this code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, o =>
        {
            o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
            o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
            };
        })
```

So, to solve this issue you have to just setup your Authentication after Identity.

Comment: @GuruStron I'll be able to do it only tomorrow. Now I can't